# Eclipse is not starting on Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, windows-7

Our company is making the move to Windows 7. After receiving the upgrade, Eclipse will no longer start on anyones machine. I first tried with 3.4 and I also tried the latest and greatest. I have the latest JDK installed as well, which is 6 update 18. This is a 32 bit machine. Any ideas? Here is the log file that Eclipse is generating:

```
!SESSION 2010-01-22 15:06:51.280 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20090917-0800
java.version=1.6.0_18
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-01-22 15:06:58.503
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (31).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.net.
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:352)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:280)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:408)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:449)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:211)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:381)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:454)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:258)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:238)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2343)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.StorageUtils.getInputStream(StorageUtils.java:94)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.load(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.<init>(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:99)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:44)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:515)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:525)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:148)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(ProxyManager.java:452)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:417)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:276)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:179)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
 ... 37 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.StorageUtils.getInputStream(StorageUtils.java:94)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.load(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesRoot.<init>(SecurePreferencesRoot.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.open(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:99)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.security.storage.SecurePreferencesMapper.getDefault(SecurePreferencesMapper.java:44)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.security.storage.SecurePreferencesFactory.getDefault(SecurePreferencesFactory.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getNode(ProxyType.java:515)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.loadProxyAuth(ProxyType.java:525)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.createProxyData(ProxyType.java:148)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType.getProxyData(ProxyType.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.migrateInstanceScopePreferences(ProxyManager.java:452)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.checkMigrated(ProxyManager.java:417)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager.initialize(ProxyManager.java:276)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.net.Activator.start(Activator.java:179)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:352)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:280)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:408)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:449)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:211)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:381)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:454)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:258)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:238)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2343)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2010-01-22 15:06:58.519
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:172)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:117)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1027)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1008)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:804)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:772)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1262)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:441)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:447)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:709)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3523)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:293)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2010-01-22 15:06:58.565
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:172)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:117)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1027)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1008)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:804)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:772)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1262)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:441)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:447)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:709)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3523)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:293)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2010-01-22 15:06:58.565
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:172)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:117)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1027)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1008)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:804)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:772)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1262)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:441)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:447)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:709)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3523)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:293)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2010-01-22 15:06:58.565
!MESSAGE Widget disposed too early!
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Widget disposed too early!
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference$1.widgetDisposed(WorkbenchPartReference.java:172)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:117)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1027)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1008)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:804)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:756)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:772)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1262)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:807)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:441)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:447)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:709)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3523)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:293)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-01-22 15:06:58.581
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.net (31).
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.activateProxyService(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:258)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:238)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2343)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Comment: I want to mention that Eclipse starts up allowing me to select a workspace, then after I select one, it crashes and tells me to view the log file.

Comment: Also I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Just for the record - I have downloaded and run both 32-bit and 64-bit Eclipses under Windows 7 Professional 64-bit without any problems.  Perhaps a path problem?  Windows is extremely picky if you place files outside your own folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I submitted a bug on the Eclipse site and it was determined that I need to execute Eclipse like so (Assuming Eclipse is installed at c:\eclipse):

```
eclipse.exe -eclipse.keyring C:\eclipse\keyring.txt
```

When Eclipse is first executed my workspace defaults to C:\eclipse\%userprofile%\workspace. For some reason, the user profile can't be determined on the installation of Windows 7 Enterprise Edition that I have. VonC you were on the right track with the parsing issue.

Description of what the above command is doing:

> From what I understand, it sets the
>   Equinox secure storage location.
>   Perhaps your % discrepancy is the
>   cause of your problems, I don't know.

Here is the URL to the bug:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300577

Comment: The overall issue and resolution can be found in my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134338/java-user-home-is-being-set-to-userprofile-and-not-being-resolved

Answer (score 5):

The `sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode()` bit suggests a special char in the path, as mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.equinox/msg03264.html).

> If I have the equinox jar in a path with a percent sign in it, equinox won't start.  For example:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/test%one
```

> More specifically, if the percent sign is a valid escaping (ie, if the dir was `/tmp/test%20`) equinox will start, however it will fail to find the `config.ini` that is located in the configuration directory.

---

Did you check the [FAQ I unzipped Eclipse, but it won't start. Why?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_I_unzipped_Eclipse%2C_but_it_won%27t_start._Why%3F)

### Cannot find a VM.

Eclipse requires a JVM to run and does not include one in the download. You need to grab a VM yourself; the Eclipse downloads page has pointers to where you can get one. You may have a VM, but Eclipse cannot find it. To avoid possible conflicts, always specify the VM you are using with the -vm command-line argument.

(see [**my eclipse.ini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) for an example to how reference the JVM)

### Bad VM.

All versions of the Eclipse Platform require at least a JDK 1.3 VM. Eclipse 3.0 requires a 1.4 VM. Eclipse 3.3 and later contain many plug-ins that will not work without a 1.5 VM, and some that even require a 1.6 VM; Eclipse will run with a lower VM, but some functionality may be missing. As of Eclipse 3.3, the recommended VM version is 1.5 or later. If you are using a home-grown or experimental JVM and encounter problems, you may not be able to get help from other Eclipse users. Use a reputable VM. If you run into trouble, always try a VM from a major distributor and see whether the problem goes away. Eclipse also may not start if there is a mismatch in the JVM's architecture and the particular Eclipse build you are using. If you are on a 64-bit system but are using a 32-bit JVM, then you should download the 32-bit version of Eclipse. Likewise, if you are using a 64-bit JVM, then you should get the 64-bit version of Eclipse.

(should not be the case here, unless somehow an other older VM is picked up by eclipse)

### Unsupported platform.

Make sure that the architecture and the operating system of your machine match one of the supported systems described in the file readme_eclipse.html. Eclipse will not run on Windows 95 or Commodore 64, for example. If your machine does not match one of the configurations described in the readme, it may still run, but you are on your own!

### Lack of appropriate native widget toolkit.

If you download, for example, the GTK version of Eclipse, then you need to make sure that you have GTK (GTK+ 2.2.1 or higher, for Eclipse 3.3) on your computer and that it is correctly installed.

### Incorrectly unzipped.

Believe it or not, about once a month, a user reports start-up failure: The user has unzipped Eclipse without selecting the use folder names option. Make sure that the result of unzipping is an install tree with an eclipse directory at its root. The Ark unzip utility in KDE is known to mangle Eclipse zips, so use a different unzip program to install there. The built-in unzip utility in Windows has also been known to have problems, particularly when installing into paths with relatively long names.

### New Eclipse unzipped on top of older Eclipse.

Do not do this. Either install Eclipse in a brand new directory or use the Eclipse Update Manager to upgrade an older Eclipse. You can still keep your old workspace. Look in the Eclipse readme file for more details.

### Buggy build.

It is not always user error. Some integration builds, and even the odd stable build, will have start-up problems under certain configurations that were not well tested. For example, build 3.0M6 would fail to start up if you restarted with an old workspace after unzipping new plug-ins into the plugins directory. If you are a new user, always start with the most recent official Eclipse release to be sure you are using the “least buggy” version possible. For more advanced users willing to accept less stable builds, consult Bugzilla to see if your particular start-up problem has already been reported.

### Xerces problem.

Prior to Eclipse 3.0, Eclipse used a version of Xerces for parsing XML files, but certain distributions of 1.4 JVMs included a different version of Xerces with the same package names. This should not be a problem with Eclipse 3.0 or higher. See FAQ 108 for more details.

### Disk full or out of memory.

Eclipse, especially 2.1 and earlier, does not always gracefully report disk-full errors or out-of-memory errors. Make sure that you have adequate disk space and that you are giving the Java VM enough heap space. See FAQ 26 for details.

Comment: My only guess from this list would be Lack of appropriate native widget toolkit due to changes in Windows 7.

Comment: @hoffmanpdirt I have udated my answer with another potential problem.

Comment: I don't have anything like that on PATH, assuming that's the Window's equivalent.

Comment: Also the config.ini file does not contain that jar file.

Answer (score 0):

One of your plugin installed is not compatible with windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you have -vm option in [eclipse dir]/eclipse.ini file then try deleting it (including path to javaw.exe).
It helped in my case when migrating from WinXP to Win7.

Comment: I tried deleting the -vm option but that doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with eclipse Indigo. I reinstalled eclipse but the problem persisted. Finally **i swapped workspace** and the the problem was solved!
So it has to do with the configurations files in the workspace... I didn't get into deeper as long as it runs i am happy :)