# What determines the location of the .grails directory?

Tags: grails

I want to change the location of the .grails directory.  I have read about using [working directories](http://naleid.com/blog/2010/05/07/using-a-unique-grails-working-directory-for-each-mercurial-branch/), but this is not what I want.  For some reason my .grails directory gets put in the "Administrator" user folder instead of in my user folder.  How do I correct this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `grailsWorkDir` property controls the location.  You can change the value in the **BuildConfig.groovy** file.

See the Grails documentation section [5.5 Customising the build](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#buildCustomising):

[image: Grails Build Properties]

---

There is an issue with Java and the `user.home` property in Windows.  See this SO question for more details:

[Java user.home is being set to %userprofile% and not being resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134338)

Comment: Neither me nor my co-worker has a `$USER_HOME` environment variable.  On his machine the `.grails` folder is put in his user folder.  On my machine the `.grails` folder is put in the "Administrator" user folder.  This is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Probably it's os-specific. What if try `echo %HOMEPATH%`?

Comment: My `%HOMEPATH%` is the same as my co-worker's, a single backslash.

Comment: The default Windows `HOMEPATH` is **C:\Documents and Settings\<username>** (XP) or **C:\Users\<username>** (W7).  A single backslash is unusual.

Comment: I.T. has a lot of crazy stuff going on here. Even when I set a `%USER_HOME%` environment variable Grails STILL puts the `.grails` directory in "Administrator" user folder instead of my user folder.

Comment: A `%HOMEPATH%` of ``\`` isn't unusual when paired with a `%HOMEDRIVE%` pointing to a network share.

Comment: @ataylor Good point.  I didn't think about AD/roaming user profiles.

Comment: @JamesA I think your answer is technically correct, but for whatever reason my PC will not comply. Rather than mess with it I'm just getting my PC re-imaged.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, the values in the registry for "Shell Folders" AND "User Shell Folders" in the registry path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" affect the user.home and in turn the location of the ".grails" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup the `user.home` JVM arg correctly on windows environment