# user.home in windows ts running eclipse rcp project

Tags: rcp, terminal-services

So me and a friend have created an application using Eclipse RCP. Now we want to distribute it using Windows Terminal Services. I have Windows TS up and running and have added about 6 accounts on it. I have also deployed my Eclipse RCP applications using the TS Remote App Manager. The application needs to create a folder in the users folder to store data, so the configuration is set up to create this folder "@user.home/...." Great, so now we try to access it from our TS Web Access site.

The first two accounts we have tried to run it on work fine, and are performing the way we desire. However, the remaining start the application but immediately give me an error message saying that we dont have access to the configuration folder at C:/Users/Administrator/... I can see the problem is that my users don't have the authority to write to the Admin folder, but I am confused as to why the user.home is referencing the Admin folder instead of the users folder. I have tried changing the users home folder in the profile and Terminal Services section of their properties but neither of these makes a difference. Does anyone know why user.home would return the Admin folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the "Home" key was not set up in the users directory. It could be fixed by following the directions in the answer found here. [Java user.home is being set to %userprofile% and not being resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134338/java-user-home-is-being-set-to-userprofile-and-not-being-resolved)