# How is the value of ${user.home} initialized?

Tags: java, java-7

```
echo %userprofile%
C:\Users\f.lastname
```

But the value of `${user.home}` is `\\LOGONSERVER\RedirectedFolders\f.lastname\` in network drive.

So how is `${user.home}` initialized and how can I change its value to the normal user profile directory?

**Resolved!**
By fixing Desktop path value in 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is defined by the JVM, not by Maven, and it's taken from the system settings. If the value is wrong, then the system isn't properly configured.

Maybe [this answer can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134338/java-user-home-is-being-set-to-userprofile-and-not-being-resolved).