# Maven doesn't recognize my user profile and looks for .m2 in another location

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I've inherited a machine from another person, and maven thinks I'm a different user. This is me:

```
C:\> echo %USERPROFILE%
C:\Users\awesomeuser
```

Although maven thinks I'm administrator and fails to create the .m2 folder there.

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from c:\apps\tools\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository
[ERROR] Could not create local repository at C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.repository.LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException: Could not create local repository at C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository
```

Any ideas how to get maven to recognize I'm awesomeuser not Administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my problem is more of this nature: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2134775/237925. I have tons of references to C:\Users\Administrator in the

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what environmental variable is causing Maven to look at the wrong home directory.

However, you can set per execution with `-s` or `--settings` option to control where to look for the settings.xml.

Alternatively you can set it globally by updating `m2.conf` in your <M2_HOME>\bin directory.  It sets the default user home.

EDIT:

I did some more research and Maven uses the Java property `user.home`.  It looks like sometimes it can be wrong and not match your user profile.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4787931

Comment: I'm more interested in having it go to my user directory by default. I don't want to manually override this every time.

Comment: Have you tried typing "set" and seeing if there are any variables set to the Administrator's home?

Comment: Updated answer with another alternative.

Comment: Yes. did all that. Turns out that my problem is more of this nature: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2134775/237925. I have tons of references to C:\Users\Administrator in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders

Comment: This answer is fuller (the second alternative about `user.home`). That linked bug explains why regedit hack in @stuff22's answer works. Basically this happens if windows home dir is changed some time after the creation of user account.