# What folder should I install Eclipse to on Windows?

Tags: windows, eclipse, windows-7

I'm running Windows 7 **with UAC enabled**. I've always found it weird that [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) doesn't use an installer and doesn't use the AppData folder to store its data in Windows, but lately I've had to reinstall it a couple times (hard drive problems) and I've been wondering if I am really putting it in the best place.

I copy the eclipse folder to my `C:\Program Files\` directory and make a shortcut on my start menu, and then pin it to my taskbar. However, eclipse has problems so I go to properties, the compatibility tab, and enable "Run as administrator". Then every time I open eclipse I have to hit yes on the UAC window, but everything works correctly, except for one side effect: my touchpad doesn't scroll any windows in eclipse. This is because the touchpad program is running as a normal user, so it can't modify eclipse running as administrator. So, then I have to close and reopen my touchpad software as an administrator.

Anyway, long story short... **Where is the best place to put the eclipse folder in Windows, and why?**

---

Edit: I just found [a possible suggestion](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t97323.html#92155438), feel free to comment. Sounds like I can just run it as administrator once the first time and set up all my plugins and such, and then run it as a normal user for my normal tasks (coding). I can't believe I never thought of doing this, but I may stick to the Program Files directory and give this approach a try unless I get a better answer here.

---

[Ninite](http://www.ninite.com/) places Eclipse in C:\eclipse. Ever since asking this question, that has been my install location for Eclipse. Eclipse still does not properly handle permissions when run out of the Program Files folder.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I setup Eclipse in

```
c:\software\eclipse_{version}\
```

I keep all my open source packages (ANT, Maven, Apache, etc) in c:\software as well.  Then I add the necessary directories to my `$PATH` variable (c:\software\ant\bin).

I also keep the Eclipse workspace under `c:\software\eclipse_workspace`.

The big plus behind this setup is portability. I can simply move the entire folder to a new drive, re-setup my path, and boom everything works.  No interference from registry settings at all.  Makes it very easy to backup.

This approached worked for XP, Windows7 RC1 and Windows7 Professional without issue.

Comment: And this works correctly with UAC enabled? If you look for software updates in Eclipse, it doesn't complain about no software sites? (this is a sign of not enough permissions, which happens when I don't run as administrator)

Comment: I believe UAC is only a problem under C:\Program Files.  There are some details in https://bugs.eclipse.org/168445 when this started being a problem in Vista.  Personally, I install eclipse and related stuff under C:\Dev\

Comment: (+) good advice still holds. Eclipse should do better than default `C:\Users\Bob\Eclipse` - user profile dirs in no way intended for engineering practises

Answer (score 5):

You can install (unzip) an eclipse:

- anywhere you want (meaning you don't have to install it on `c:\Program Files` (I install it for instance on `c:\prog\java\eclipse`, a directory tree I create
- with a workspace set anywhere you want (for me: `c:\prog\java\workspace`, and I reference that workspace in **[my eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)**.
  This is important because the default location of a workspace (using user.home) is not always a good idea (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120160/eclipse-is-not-starting-on-windows-7/2121460#2121460) and its [associated eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300577) which will be solved only with the upcoming eclipse Helios 3.6)
- with plugins set anywhere you want through a **[Dropins folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059732/a-new-version-of-eclipse-just-came-out-is-there-anything-i-can-do-to-avoid-havi/1060598#1060598)** (also referenced in the eclipse.ini, for me: `c:\prog\java\myplugins`)
- with a [JVM installed anywhere you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305097/installation-of-eclipse/2305466#2305466) (also referenced in the eclipse.ini, for me: `c:\prog\java\jdks\jdk6u18`, and I have installed several others jdks in `c:\prog\java\jdks`)

Eclipse shouldn't ever *have* to be in `c:\Program Files`, and the setting describe above works perfectly with:

- Vista or Seven, UAC fully activated
- XP, with no Administrator rights.

Comment: Well I mean, I know it doesn't NEED to be installed in Program Files, I just don't create my own program folders, and UAC seems to guard the Program Files directory (same with the Windows folder and probably others) so that things need raised privileges to modify it. So in essence you are telling me to place Eclipse anywhere I want, that isn't protected by UAC.

Comment: @Ricket: exactly. And not just Eclipse. Its workspace, plugins and JVM (both for executing Eclipse itself and for programming) can be placed anywhere you want, especially where UAC won't bother you.

Answer (score 4):

I usually install Eclipse to [%LocalAppData%](https://www.howtogeek.com/318177/what-is-the-appdata-folder-in-windows/).

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Eclipse\<version>\
```

- Common install path used by Google Chrome, Python, GitHub Desktop, Discord, and f.lux
- Only installs Eclipse for the current user profile. (separate per-user settings)
- Does not require administrator privileges
- Accessible as a default [Windows environment variable](https://www.askvg.com/list-of-environment-variables-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/) (`%LocalAppData%`)
- Folder is designated specifically to hold application data

Answer (score 1):

You could put it under your `User` folder or `My Documents` folder, so you don't have to worry about permissions. Then just add a link to your start menu / quick start / desktop and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have many different versions of Eclipse and related products installed. So I have them installed as `C:\Eclipse\...` for Windows and `/Eclipse/...` under Mac and Linux. Usually with the directory name as the base name of the zip - e.g. `eclipse-rcp-helios-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64`... Some products, like those from IBM, have their own ideas and can often not be changed...

As for the workspaces - yes, I have one for each customer - they are placed under `/Eclipse/Workspaces/...` and friends.

And the target platforms are placed under `/Eclipse/TargetPlatforms/...` and friends.