# msysgit - sh.exe - fork: Permission denied - Vista 64 bit

Tags: git, msysgit, vista64

I installed msysgit on other Windows machines with no problems.  On this Vista 64 bit Ultimate box, I installed the 3 most recent versions of msysgit.  On all three installs, when I do a "git bash here", I get exactly this on the command window:

```
sh.exe": fork: Permission denied
sh.exe"-3.1$
```

The git command doesn't work.  I get the same permission denied message.  Any clues as to how to fix this?

**Update**

Also, when I do "git gui here" - I get:

```
Cannot determine Git version.

couldn't execute "C\...\git-core\git.exe

Git Gui requires Git 1.5.0 or later
```

I'm using a version newer than 1.5.0.

Comment: Do you have Cygwin installed?

Comment: @VonC: msysgit works without Cygwin, that's why you use it in the first place.. – @Steve: What command are you actually using? `git bash` doesn't exist.

Comment: @poke: true, but if you had Cygwin installed (independently from your msysgit installation), some side-effect might appear. Hence my question. And **"`git bash here`" does exist**, not as a command per se, but as a contextual menu to bring up a bash shell window on the current path.

Comment: @VonC - No Cygwin. Svn and TortoiseSvn are on the machine but I would think that has nothing to do with it.

@poke - git --version doesn't work.  Actually git anything doesn't work.  I keep getting permission denied.

I tried all 3 options on the screen that asks what kind of prompt.  The last option, windows and unix, when I do git bash here, completely fails.

Comment: Is the git\cmd directory in your path?

Comment: @poke - No, what do you mean, c:/program files (x86)/git/cmd?

Comment: Yeah, when I installed msysgit, it automatically added `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` to the PATH (you had to select that you want to support custom shells during the install).

Comment: I added it - still the same error.  I tried adding bin too.  On the install, I stuck with the first option - bash only though.

Comment: @Steve: uninstall, and retry the installation with option 2 "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt": it won't prevent you to run git in a bash shell, but it might work better overall.

Comment: @Steve: try also to install it in a custom directory (not `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files(x86)` but `C:\myTools\Git` for instance)

Comment: @VonC: Ding, ding, ding, ding! We have a winner. I combined both your steps, so not sure which did it, but I tried the win cmd prmpt before and it didn't work, so maybe it was the path.  Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Looks good - I got the remote clone to work, so hopefully push and pulls will too.  I actually started a repository in Mercurial.  Hopefully that will wait till much later.

Comment: @Steve: all right, I have made an answer reflecting the "correct" steps ("correct" as in "actually working" ;) ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual way I install msysgit is:

- not in `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files(x86)`
  (That avoid any issue with the UAC mechanism: I had the [same "permission denied" problem with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414181/in-windows-where-should-the-eclipse-folder-be-placed/2414678#2414678), and [this kind of program shouldn't be installed in `Program Files` anyway](https://serverfault.com/questions/120681/how-important-is-it-to-install-on-the-program-files-folder).)
- with the option "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt": minimal impact on the `PATH`, and avoid side-effect with an eventual Cygwin already installed.

It never failed to work this way.

Comment: @Steve: I just saw http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/ae733d166dc4c8fa and I too would like to know the difference between "Git for Windows" and msysgit. I have always thought of msysgit as Git for Windows!

Comment: +10 if I could. Every time I switched branches, I was getting the permission denied error and a random number of files weren't getting written. I had to revert all changes before being able to continue. Uninstalling mysysgit and reinstalling to c:\git resolved the issue.