# Hudson slave using msysGit shell

Tags: windows, shell, hudson, msysgit

I have got a Hudson Slave on a windows machine and need to execute some shell commands on it. I have put all the commands in the execute shell portion of the project and the first line reads as this:

```
#!C:\msysgit\msysgit\bin\sh.exe
```

However when running the project I am getting errors saying command not found. Specifically for git, cd, make, rm and I would presume more. I feel like this is a simple thing to fix but can't figure it out. The script works fine when using msysGit on the machine but I am having trouble doing it through Hudson. Any help would be appreciated. I need to be using msysGit not Cygwin.

Comment: I figured out, all I needed to do was change it to 
'#!C:\msysgit\msysgit\bin\sh.exe --login -i'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by making that script displays:

- the username
- the path
- the `$HOME` (important for ssh operation, and [not always set correctly on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454774/fix-msysgit-portable-home-location/3455231#3455231))

And see what those variables reference in the context of an Hudson job.
They might not reflect/inherit the values of your current session.
And it can depend on [how you did install msysgit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439336/msysgit-sh-exe-fork-permission-denied-vista-64-bit/2439777#2439777).

---

The [OP Zack Lalanne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778228/zack-lalanne) mentions in the comment he just need to have:

```
 #!C:\msysgit\bin\sh.exe --login -i
```

which means the bash session will inherit his environment variables, making the job much likely to run than without the user's environment.