# error: unable to unlink old 'gulpfile.js' (Permission denied) while using Docker Compose for development environment

Tags: git, symfony, docker, permissions, docker-compose

I'm developing a PHP 7.1 web application using the following:

- Symfony 3.2
- Docker Compose 1.12.0
- Ubuntu 16.04 x64

When running `docker-compose up -d`, my bind mounted project directory's owner and group are changed to root. Thus, whenever I try to commit a change or pull from my remote with `git pull`, I'll see the following:

```
error: unable to unlink old 'gulpfile.js' (Permission denied)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD^'.
```

[Changing the project directory's owner and group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774397/git-push-error-unable-to-unlink-old-permission-denied) back to my user removes the error. Is there an easier way to prevent these user permission conflicts while developing with Docker Compose?

**EDIT**
Here is an overview of my current directory structure:

```
dockerComposeAndProjectDir/
|-- projectDirectory/
|-- dockerComposeDirectory/
    |-- docker-compose.yml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [docker (err... moby!) issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259)

> If you `chown` the volume (on the host side) before bind-mounting it, it will work.
>   In that case, you could do:

```
mkdir /tmp/www
chown 101:101 /tmp/www
docker run -v /tmp/www:/var/www ubuntu stat -c "%U %G" /var/www
```

> (Assuming that `101:101` is the `UID:GID` of the `www-data` user in your container.)
>
> Another possibility is to do the bind-mount, then chown inside the container.
>
> Using volumes just works assuming the image has data at the path your mounting to.
>   Using binds uses the host path's UID/GID.
>   UID/GID in the container is the same as UID/GID on the host... even if user/group names don't match, UID/GID is what matters here.

I refered the [OP lolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6530413/lolsky) to [`phpdocker-io/base-images/php/7.1` Dockerfile](https://github.com/phpdocker-io/base-images/blob/master/php/7.1/fpm/Dockerfile).
The OP concludes:

> The `php:7.1-fpm` Dockerfile indicates that the `php-fpm` service would be run as `www-data`, so I was incorrect about the container's user.
>   Chowning the volume after the initial bind mount seems to work.
>   Anytime the volume needs to be recreated by Docker Compose, I have to chown it again, which gets a little annoying, but it does solve my issue.

Comment: I tried chowning the volume from my host using the UID and GID for my user before running `docker-compose up -d`. However, after the up command ran my bind mounted project directory still got root as the owner and group.

Comment: Looking at the issue you posted, I'm not sure anyone has found a solution other than manually changing the owner/group using an entrypoint script after the container has mounted the volume.

Comment: @ChristianElowsky You need to make sure the uid/gid are the same in the host and in the container.

Comment: @ChristianElowsky I thought it was working since you accepted the answer?.

Comment: I'm using a _PHP7.1-fpm_ container, which runs as the **root** user. For my _nginx_ container, it was easy to make sure the UID of the **www-data** user was the same as my host user UID. I put `RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data` in the Dockerfile right before `CMD`. However, putting `RUN usermod -u 1000 root` before `CMD` for the _PHP7.1-fpm_ container fails with `usermod: user root is currently used by process 1`
`ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c usermod -u 1000 root' returned a non-zero code: 8`, since **root** is probably already in use by Docker.

Comment: Your initial answer did work for volumes mounted by my _nginx:latest_ container which runs as **www-data**, but not _php:7.1-fpm_ which runs as **root**. For containers that must run as **root**, this issue is still unresolved.

Comment: @ChristianElowsky Can you check if https://github.com/phpdocker-io/base-images/blob/master/php/7.1/fpm/Dockerfile contains any clues?

Comment: The *php:7.1-fpm* Dockerfile indicates that the php-fpm service would be run as **www-data**, so I was incorrect about the container's user. Chowning the volume after the initial bind mount seems to work. Anytime the volume needs to be recreated by Docker Compose, I have to chown it again, which gets a little annoying, but it does solve my issue. I'll look into other possibilities in the Github issue you linked to ensure the bind mount is owned by the host user regardless of whether or not it's being recreated.