# Pull request give some error related to permission denied

Tags: git, github

When i pull it on dev server i am getting this error.

Updating c740436..8bf72a7

error: unable to unlink old 'unumber-nomination/application/config/config.php' (Permission denied)

error: unable to unlink old 'unumber-nomination/application/config/constants.php' (Permission denied)

I tried to give permission but still getting this error.Any idea

Comment: Try looking at some of the proposed answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774397/git-push-error-unable-to-unlink-old-permission-denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By giving permission to the specific folder pull request is working fine.The user don't have permission for this directory unumber-nomination thats why pull request is failed due to permission. After giving permission pull request working fine.