# git warnings about unable to unlink git objects. How do I resolve this?

Tags: git

When I do a git commit I see the following

```
>$ git commit -a
warning: unable to unlink .git/objects/63/tmp_obj_kK6IC9: Invalid argument
warning: unable to unlink .git/objects/2c/tmp_obj_SFNGla: Invalid argument
```

I can still perform git commit. However, I want to know how to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: try running the same command with the `--verbose` flag so we can get some more debug output.

Comment: there is no extra debug output except that it shows the code differences for the files I am about to commit

Comment: Hmm, do you have any programs that might be holding those files 'in use', like a graphical interface? (suggested based off this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199496/git-checkout-warning-unable-to-unlink-files-permission-denied)

Comment: Please state the type of the filesystem your git directory is located on (e.g. `df -T .git`).

Comment: the files are saved in NTFS on a cruzer fit drive. I am using mac os x. The reason why my mac os x can use a NTFS is because I have Paragon. Is that the reason why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had a similar problem on OS X whenever trying to run "git repack" or "git gc", and I finally solved it after coming across this page: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20010610132749532

The fix is to open a terminal, go to your git repo, cd into the .git folder, and then type `chflags -R nouchg *`. If that was the issue, then after that, your git commands will work as normal.

Answer (score 5):

only delete `./git/gc.log` file .

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same Problem on Windows 10. Following a hint [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/29758/i-get-fatal-unable-to-access-configgitconfig-inval.html) I suspect a company-logon-script in combination with the home drive mapped to a network drive. Logging off and back on solves it for me.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: Why? It's a solution to the question above that might help other users. Additionally: as a new user, I can only comment on my own questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure nothing is running and try to checkout a new branch, if can't try git checkout -f master, then  the warning won't appear again.