# git: Branches that don't look like branches

Tags: git, github, merge, phpstorm

I've never gotten the hang of git, and I only work on programming off and on, so I forget the status of my projects. At the moment I'm not making sense of what git is telling me about old branches.

`git branch -a` says:

```
  dashboard
* master
  php7
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/php7
```

So it says I have two branches besides master: `dashboard` and `php7`. I remember `php7` clearly - it was a big chunk of work with many commits. I don't remember `dashboard`, but the name tells me what file it was related to.

`git branch --merged` says:

```
  dashboard
* master
  php7
```

So apparently both are merged. But `php7` is known on remote while `dashboard` is not. I don't remember what git commands I did to get to this point.

When I look at the log in PHPStorm (or with `git log --graph`) those two don't look like what I would expect a branch to look like - there is no diverted line with commits on it. Here is the most recent section of the log:
[image]

Mysteries (at least to me):

- Commits I remember doing on the `php7` branch are all on the same orange line as `master`. If I merged and then deleted the branch (logical), why is it still listed as a branch at all?
- Why is there an extra "origin" label on the last of the `php7` branch? I would think recent pushes would cause remote to look just like local, with only one "origin" label on the latest commit. Surely remote doesn't consider `php7` to be not-yet-merged - that would be horrible, as that code is critical.
- `dashboard` is not known by remote at all (https://github.com/OsakaWebbie/kizunadb) - how could that be?

On the other hand, earlier in the log there is a very obvious branch that had two commits and then was merged, which is not in the list of branches:
[image]
I would be happy to delete it (I don't keep old branches for nostalgia), but `git branch -d texlabels` says: `error: branch 'texlabels' not found.` The most branchy-looking thing in the log isn't a branch? My head hurts.

I'm sure you git gurus will immediately know what this all means and how to clean it up - I look forward to clarity.

### Update:

Thanks to Kata for a thorough answer (very likely to be accepted). But I have a few followup questions that would be hard to read in a tiny comment (I wish comments could be longer and have more formatting), so bear with me a little longer. I guess they can be answered either by a comment or by Kata adding to his answer - whatever works.

> Because it is not sure that in the past `php7` was merged into master.

If it's not sure that `php7` was merged, why is it listed in `--merged`? (The thought of git being "unsure" about anything worries me...) I have no idea how to move a branch head later, so that scenario is unlikely. However, there was a time when I did something locally that caused Github to refuse pushes (I think I might have amended files to an already-pushed commit) - someone else helped me look it over, and I ended up doing `push -f` (I'm the only developer). Perhaps that caused a pointer to get out of place...

Anyway, I *know* the `php7` code is part of my current codebase, because it is happily running on PHP7 now. And I recognize several of the commits as having been done on that branch. In fact, it's possible that *all* the commits from the time I created `php7` until I merged it (46 commits) were done on that branch (i.e. no flipping back to master to fix bugs in the meantime). Would that explain why there is no extra line in the DAG beside the master line?

If so, then perhaps `texlabels` is the only branch I ever interrupted to fix a bug on master, since it's the only extra line in the DAG. Also, no other branch has an entry for "Merge branch 'so-and-so'" - is it because without any master commits, merge doesn't need to change any content (just move pointers)?

> Because `dashboard` was created locally and has never pushed to remote.

Oh, I didn't realize that a basic push doesn't include branch information. Apparently Github knows about `php7` because I no doubt did pushes while it was checked out. (Is that right?)

I've also now learned about tags, and I created a tag at the point I deployed my project on a new server with PHP7 and other differences. I would be happy to not have the `php7` or `dashboard` branches anymore, as long as my current codebase stays my current codebase. But if you're saying that there is some uncertainty about their merge status, is it safe to delete them? (Deleting things sounds scary, but if it's merely a pointer...)

### Update #2:

After Kata mentioned that without `--all` I might not be seeing everything, I did a diff between with/without that flag. I discovered that at the very beginning of my `php7` work, the first four commits were repeated, first on a "branchy-looking" branch (only seen in `--all`), and then on the main line with everything else. Here is the relevant snippet from `git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline`:

```
* 3b1c25a Removal of .html files (won't work with the new server config) and $client in db connect file
* dccc3f3 minor edits
* 20a1aab remove .idea files from repo
* 629d891 Second day of cleanup for PHP7: various things, hacking away at errors one at a time (note: I
* a669fa0 First day of cleanup for PHP7:   * mysql_ to mysqli_ (major functions, anyway)   * convert my
| * 51738d1 (refs/original/refs/heads/php7) minor edits
| * f1aa0f9 remove .idea files from repo
| * 38aef9b (refs/original/refs/remotes/origin/php7) Second day of cleanup for PHP7: various things, ha
| * cfcaa51 First day of cleanup for PHP7:   * mysql_ to mysqli_ (major functions, anyway)   * convert
|/
* 294ef21 Feature: batch category delete
```

I'm guessing that the weirdness was somehow caused by me accidentally using the command line on my VM to do two of the four ("remove .idea..." & "minor edits") instead of OsakaWebbie like the rest of them. (The user doesn't show in `--oneline`, but you can see that on Github.) But no matter how it happened, I'm assuming the first set (cfcaa51 thru 51738d1) will go away when I delete the branch, but since they are repeated (and I know my current codebase reflects the changes in those commits), it should be okay, right?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what a branch is. In another VCS I was using before git, a branch used to be a sequence of committed versions of a file. That is not the case in git. In git, a branch is just a pointer to a specific commit. A branch and a tag is almost the same thing. They are both references to/aliases for one specific commit. (The only difference is that if you make commits while you have a branch checked out, you will move the branch pointer to the new commit, whereas a tag will always stay on the same commmit).

Comment: In your example, you merged the `texlabels` branch at some point in the past. Since that point of time, you have removed the `texlabels` branch (there is no longer a branch pointing to a commit in the purple line of history in the picture). But you still have a merge commit as part of your history. That cannot be changed, unless you rewrite history (and rewriting history is generally a bad thing to be doing, unless you really know what you are doing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better to think branches as **heads** (or pointers). What `git log` shows you is a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of the commits and a list of heads pointing to particular commits. What you can see at the current moment is something like: the `php7` head is pointing to this commit. You cannot know in the past how the `php7` head was moving since `git` allows us to move heads in a free manner.

Regarding `git branch --merged [<commit>]`, look into its [document](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), the command simply shows all the heads that can be reached from the `<commit>`. In your case, the `<commit>` is `HEAD` which means `master`. So the result is obvious: `dashboard`, `master`, and `php7` are reachable from `HEAD`. *Notice that by default `git branch` does not show remote heads, add `-a` option for that*.

Now I think your questions could be answered.

> Commits I remember doing on the php7 branch are all on the same orange line as master. If I merged and then deleted the branch (logical), why is it still listed as a branch at all?

Because it is not sure that in the past `php7` was merged into `master`. Even if it was, it could be always that at some point later the `php7` **head** was moved, so we cannot see the vestige of the merge caused by `php7`.

> Why is there an extra "origin" label on the last of the php7 branch? I would think recent pushes would cause remote to look just like local, with only one "origin" label on the latest commit. Surely remote doesn't consider php7 to be not-yet-merged - that would be horrible, as that code is critical.

That label simply means that currently there are 2 heads -- `php7` and `origin/php7` -- pointing to that commit.

> dashboard is not known by remote at all (https://github.com/OsakaWebbie/kizunadb) - how could that be?

Because `dashboard` was created locally and has never been pushed to remote.

> I would be happy to delete it (I don't keep old branches for nostalgia), but git branch -d texlabels says: error: branch 'texlabels' not found. The most branchy-looking thing in the log isn't a branch? My head hurts.

You know the existing of the `texlabels` head just because you see its name in the commit message. But actually that head was deleted in the past thus at the moment you cannot delete it again.

### Update:

*To answer some more concerns of @OsakaWebbie*

The `--merged` option is named based on the fact that, in **normal development** (i.e., you don't abnormally move heads, with `git reset` for example), if a head `child` can reach to a head `parent`, it means that `parent` was merged into `child` at some point in the past. In other words, `child` does inherit `parent`.

```
----------------------- child
         /
        /
     parent
```

But I empathise with you about this, actually there are [complaints](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/10/24/whats-wrong-with-git-a-conceptual-design-analysis/) about the naming of `git` commands and their options.

Back to the story of your `php7` head, I think the situation should be clear now.

A merge does not necessarily cause two paths joining into one. Indeed, as you told, since you switched to `php7` and appended 46 commits to it, you hadn't appended any commit to `master`, so the history before the merge looks like this:

```
----------------- master
                    \
                     ----------------- php7
```

Then you switched back to `master` and made the merge: `git merge php7`. Because `php7` is a child of `master`, the result of the merge should be exactly `php7`. Thus, `git` will simply move `master` forward and point it to the commit being pointed by `php7`. This kind of merge is called **fast-forward**. Then you have:

```
-------------------
                    \
                     ----------------- php7, master
```

which essentially is:

```
-------------------------------------- php7, master
```

But fast-forward did not happen with the merge of `texlabels` head. You created the head, switched to it, coded something and appended some commits. Then you switched back to `master`, also coded something and appended some commits. So you have:

```
----------------- master
     \
      ----------- texlabels
```

As you see `texlabels` is not a child of `master`. Hence this cannot be a fast-forward, merging `texlabels` into `master` will cause:

```
----------------- (old master) -- master
     \                         /
      ----------- texlabels
```

That's why it is the only branchy-looking thing in the history.

Regarding your two last concerns:

> Oh, I didn't realize that a basic push doesn't include branch information. Apparently Github knows about php7 because I no doubt did pushes while it was checked out. (Is that right?)

`git push <remote> [<head>]` only pushes the provided `<head>` (and its ancestor commits of course). If `<head>` is not provided, then the head that is being pointed by `HEAD` will be used -- it is `php7` in your case. To push all the heads, use `--all` option.

> But if you're saying that there is some uncertainty about their merge status, is it safe to delete them? (Deleting things sounds scary, but if it's merely a pointer...)

Yes, heads are merely pointers, but please be careful: after deleting a head, some commits may be abandoned -- i.e., they cannot be reached from any head -- and will be cleaned (deleted) by the `GC` of `git`. If you are sure about what you are deleting, go ahead.

---

Some more notes:

1. The `push -f` is not related here, it causes unexpected things in the remote (e.g., [losing some commits](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)), not in the local.
2. By default `git log` shows only the commits that can be reached from `HEAD`, use `--all` option to show all commits.

### Update #2:

*About the 4 extra commits*

It's very likely that at the commit `51738d1 minor edits` you issued a `git filter-branch` [command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to massively modify something about those 4 commits (modify author names -- I guess). Then you had 4 new commits created (from a669fa0 to 3b1c25a). The 4 old commits (from cfcaa51 to 51738d1) are still there because they are still reachable from the heads `refs/original/...`. These heads were created by the backing-up mechanism of `git filter-branch`.

You are totally safe to [delete those 4 extra commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52401636/2198705). They are completely unrelated to the 4 "main" commits.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderfully thorough answer. I'm starting to understand more, but I have auxiliary questions based on your answer and what I have studied since. Please check the "Update" section of my question.

Comment: Thanks again. The mud in my brain is definitely clearing up. I already accepted your answer, but I'm hoping you'll respond one more time - I added a short "Update #2" to my question. This should be the last go-around.

Comment: Is your link suggesting that I manually remove a whole chunk of the directory structure? `rm -Rf .git/refs/original`? Just confirming, since it seems drastic and I don't understand it well enough to anticipate side effects. I tried dipping my toe in by doing just `git gc`, but that didn't remove the four commits.

Comment: That folder contains the heads you want to delete. So delete it, it’s safe.

Comment: Deleted. But then `git gc` fails - it wants to remove files but can't. There's always this one: `rm: cannot remove ‘/var/www/kizunadb/public/.git/objects/pack/old-pack-[somenumber].pack’: Operation not permitted`, and sometimes hundreds of warnings like: `unable to unlink .git/objects/01/[somenumber]: Operation not permitted`. It's a VM - I can delete files on the Windows host (I tried just the old-pack ones - I'm scared to do the others, in case gc needs them **before** unlinking), but not on the CentOS guest, even as root. Googling has not given any clues.

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827676/git-warnings-about-unable-to-unlink-git-objects-how-do-i-resolve-this

Comment: Thanks, but that thread was even less applicable than the one I had previously found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199496/git-checkout-warning-unable-to-unlink-files-permission-denied I even tried halting and restarting my VM, but to no avail. This is getting off-topic, so I'll write a new question for this issue.